# Simultaneous input/output on input element

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

I have a web audio player, and below is a very basic simulation of how the seekbar works.  I've got a standard progress bar showing how far the audio track has played, and then to allow user input I've got an input bar over the top which only appears on hover.

The user can then select a new point to play audio from.  However it annoys me that the input bar doesn't update with the track - on hover, the handle is always at the wrong place.

Is there a way to update the input handle position, without blocking user input?  When I push an update to the input to update it from JS, I've been having issues where it blocks or ignores any user input.  Is there a nice way to make this work?

```js
var p = document.getElementById("progress");
var r = document.getElementById("input");
var i = 0;

r.addEventListener("change", function() {
  i = parseInt(r.value);
});


function playSecond(n) {
  if (i < n) {
    i++;
    p.value = i;
    setTimeout(playSecond, 500, n);
  }
}
playSecond(101);
```

```css
#seekbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

#seekbar progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

#seekbar input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

#seekbar:hover input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="seekbar">
  <progress id="progress" max="100" value="0"></progress>
  <input id="input" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan No I don't think so?  Your first comment, changing the progress value will get overridden by the JS function updating it from the audio.  The second comment, starting a new function could cause 2 audios to play simultaneously.  Either way, I don't think these examples will update the input value?

Comment: Then I do not get what you are trying to do. Perhaps if you make your snippet a [mcve] using some file on the net?

Comment: I want the input handle to update in line with the progress bar, but when I do this in Javascript it blocks or ignores user input.  If a javascript function is pushing updated values to the input bar constantly, and a user tries to seek to a different point using the input bar, it doesn't work as Javascript overrides the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

I moved the slider while testing to make it easier to see/grab and added a debug span

```js
var p = document.getElementById("progress");
var r = document.getElementById("input");
var o = document.getElementById("output");
var i = 0;

r.addEventListener("change", function() {
  i = parseInt(r.value);
});


function playSecond(n) {
  if (i < n) {
    i++;
    p.value = i;
    r.value = i;    
    output.textContent = i;
    setTimeout(playSecond, 500, n);
  }
}
playSecond(101);
```

```css
#seekbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

#seekbar progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

#seekbar input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100000;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#seekbar:hover input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="seekbar">
  <progress id="progress" max="100" value="0"></progress>
  <hr/>
  <input id="input" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
  <span id="output"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good sample but I think that helps to highlight the problem - if you click and drag on the input bar, and then hold for a second before releasing, you'll see it jumping about.  A couple of times it didn't work for me either I'm afraid, maybe releasing it at the point where the JS function is about to update it can cause this?

Comment: I wondered if there's a way to detect that the user is hovering or selected the input, and disable the update?  Not sure if it's possible to detect that though!

Comment: Of course. .addEventListener("mouseover") /mouseout/ mouseenter/mouseleave

Comment: That's a good shout, but how would I handle it on mobile devices?  I'd have to detect if the user is in the action of changing the input before it has actually changed as there's no mouse.  Sorry, I don't want to be a pain but I've been struggling with this and haven't found a nice solution yet because there's so many things to allow for.

Comment: touchstart/touchend